# Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net

I have visual studio 2005 and now I added 2008 also.When I am creating an application in 2008,it works no problem I saw property of application target version is 3.5.But when I am making any mistake error page shows in botton version 2.0My operating system is xp.Shall I need to load framwork 3.5 externally.

Comment: Version 2.0 of what? Keep in mind that .NET Framework 3.5 runs on the CLR 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

> Version 3.5 of the .NET Framework was
>   released on 19 November 2007, but it
>   is not included with Windows Server
>   2008. As with .NET Framework 3.0, version 3.5 uses the CLR of version
>   2.0. In addition, it installs .NET Framework 2.0 SP1, (installs .NET
>   Framework 2.0 SP2 with 3.5 SP1) and
>   .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 (installs .NET
>   Framework 3.0 SP2 with 3.5 SP1), which
>   adds some methods and properties to
>   the BCL classes in version 2.0 which
>   are required for version 3.5 features
>   such as Language Integrated Query
>   (LINQ). These changes do not affect
>   applications written for version 2.0,
>   however.

Taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5)

Answer (score -1):

yes,

When you upgrade the your project from framework 2.0 to 3.5 then it is not update all control.
Like it uses some of control 2.0.

So for this you need to manually create all page and copy code from 2005 to 2008 page.